# JavaScript event handler to insert new pre tag

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, pre

I have a set of 3 pre tags that are editable. When someone is on one of the lines and hits 'enter', I want it to insert a new tag below (in the document tree) the one it is on. I have tried to put an event handler on the tags so that this occurs, but the 'onkeypress' doesn't seem to be firing.

```
<script>
    function handlers(){
        var pres = document.getElementsByTagName("pre");
        for(i=0; i<pres.length;i++){
            pres[i].addEventListener("onkeypress", function(e){
                if(e.which != 13) return;//the ENTER key
                var tag = e.srcElement;
                if(tag.nextSibling){
                    var next = tag.nextSibling;
                    var newPre = document.createElement('pre');
                    tag.nextSibling = newPre;
                    newPre.nextSibling = next;
                }
            var tree = document.getElementById("tree");
            tree.innerHTML = document.getElementByTagName().length;
            });
        }
    }
</script>
<body onload="handlers();">
    <div id="editor" contentEditable="true">
        <pre>1</pre>
        <pre>2</pre>
        <pre>3</pre>
    </div>

    <div>
    <p id="tree"></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are iterating over the array of elements incorrectly, and you are not attaching event listeners correctly.

I recommend changing your for loop to:

```
for (var i=0, l=pres.length; i<l; i++) {
    pres[i];//This is where the Element is stored
}
```

You can read up on attaching event listeners [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)

Additionally, it would appear: http://jsfiddle.net/vZYpX that the source of the keypress event under "contentEditable" is the actual element that is "contentEditable". So you have to either make the `<pre>`s content editable (and not the div), or attach the listener to the parent div (that is currently contentEditable).

Comment: Oh whoops I was doing python iteration which is through an array as opposed to through the attributes in JS. I altered it accordingly and added the correct event listeners, but am still not seeing anything

Comment: @Chris the `addEventListener` takes event types without the `on` prefix. e.g. `pres[i].addEventListener("keypress", function(e){`

Comment: oh man they just sneak up on you. Okay, that's now good and I put an alert at the start of the function just to see if it gets there, but it never does.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the 'onkeypress' can be fired from 'pre' tag.

However I have a suggestion: 
1. Register document.onmousemove to detect mouse position.
2. Register document.onkeypress event and when detecting the 'enter' key, check if the mouse is over a 'pre' tag. If so, run your code.

It should look like this:

```
function moveMoveHandler(e)
{
    var evt = window.event || e;
    window.lastMouseX = evt.clientX;
    window.lastMouseY = evt.clientY;
}


function keypressHandler(e)
{
    var evt = window.event || e;

    // handling only 'enter' key
    if (evt.keyCode !== 13) return;

    // getting the element the mouse is on
    var elem = document.elementFromPoint(window.lastMouseX,window.lastMouseY);
    var node = elem;
    // checking if the found node is a child of a 'pre' node
    while (node.nodeName !== "PRE" && node !== document.body)
          node = node.parentNode;        

    if (node.nodeName === "PRE")
    {
         ... INSERT YOUR CODE HERE ...
    }
}


// IE
if (window.attachEvent)
{
   document.attachEvent("onkeypress", keypressHandler);
   document.attachEvent("onmousemove", moveMoveHandler);
}
// other browsers
else 
{
   document.addEventListener("keypress", keypressHandler, false);
   document.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMoveHandler, false);
}
```

Comment: pre does have an onkeypress handler because it is editable. The problem with your solution is the mouse may not be hovering over that particular pre tag when enter is hit. Also, no need to worry about IE :)

Comment: Chris, I'm not sure I understand your comment. In my solution when the user hit the 'enter' key we check if the mouse is hover a pre tag  and you can enter any condition you want...